# Can't upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, system-installation, updates, 14.10

I was trying to upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.10 LTS and when I tried to do it via the GUI and from the terminal (`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `sudo do-release-upgrade`) I get:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state
```

Comment: 14.10 is not LTS. What is the point to upgrade from LTS to non-LTS?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are trying to upgrade from 14.04 -which is indeed an LTS version- to 14.10, which is *not* LTS.

Since 14.04 is still supported, most of your software is up to date to much the same way as if you went to 14.10. So there is no real need to upgrade. Please note, 14.04 will be supported until April 2019, and 14.10 only up to *July this year*, so you are in fact taking a step backwards.

If this is a production machine, I would strongly recommend staying with 14.04 until the next LTS version rolls along.

On the other hand, if this computer is just for testing and all your personal data is fully backed up, you could consider trying the following:

- as root, edit manually the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, replacing all occurrences of `trusty` with `utopic`.
- `sudo aptitude update`
- `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`

This procedure has been known to work to upgrade between Debian versions. It will take quite some time and download in excess of 600 MBytes for a base Ubuntu system (more if more software is installed), but if it succeeds will leave you with a Utopic (14.10) system with the same selection of software you currently have installed.

I would not recommend trying to upgrade directly to Vivid (15.04), since the change from *upstart* to *systemd* may very well have changed system package dependencies sufficiently to completely mix up the software manager.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove all your custom added ppa's for any update to run.

In *System Settings* go to *Software & Updates* and move to the *Other Software* tab.

I believe all your custom ppa's must be unchecked from this list for the update to run, then you can recheck them (and test them individually) after the update has occurred.